# Object array with identifier: use index to quickly access elements by id?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I must access the elements of an object array very often by an identifier id, i.e.

```
[
{id:1, value:“test“, cat:2},
{id:2, value:“test“, cat:2},
{id:3, value:“test“, cat:2}, ...
]
```

To do so I use find, for example to fetch the value of object with id 3:

```
  SomeVal = myArray.find(x => x.id === 3).value
```

However, as I would never change the initial array after creation, and as the id of each item is well defined (I fetch the objects from my sql db), I was thinking to use the array index as identifier. I would use splice to create such array initially and I would start with id 1. I have around 5k objects.

This way I must not use find, but instead could access the array by the index directly:

```
 SomeVal = myArray[3].value
```

As my id starts with 1, the array would be of same size in the end.

I would think that’s an enormous performance boost, yet I have never seen anyone going such an approach when accessing elements by an identifier. What do you think?

Comment: Any example/real world scenario where you feel this approach is applicable or can be used? The above example is very specific one where all the conditions match

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is basically a `Map` or `Object` that revolves around a very specific rule. That rule being the id directly correlates to the index in the array. The advantage an `Array` has over other data structures, with superior search speeds, is the fact that they are ordered. If order doesn't matter and you're purely using it to leverage search, `Set`s and `Map`s do a better job